# Yii is unable to find action login in Admin module

Tags: module, yii

See the following code of the

```
<?php

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Displays the login page
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $model = new LoginForm;

        // collect user input data
        if (isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if ($model->validate() && $model->login())
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl',
        );
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow all users to perform the 'login' action
                'actions' => array('login'),
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow the admin user to perform everything
                'actions' => array('*'),
                'users' => array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny', // deny all users
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

The problem is, when I go to my module: `/?r=admin` I am redirected to `/?r=site/index` my default site controller.

How can this happen?

Edit: (added AdminModule)

```
<?php

class AdminModule extends CWebModule
{

    public function init()
    {
        // this method is called when the module is being created
        // you may place code here to customize the module or the application
        // import the module-level models and components
        $this->setImport(array(
            'admin.models.*',
            'admin.components.*',
        ));

        $this->setComponents(array(
            'user' => array(
                'loginUrl' => Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/default/login'),
            )
        ));
    }

    public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
    {
        if (parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action))
        {
            // this method is called before any module controller action is performed
            // you may place customized code here

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

As you see I added loginUrl via setComponents, but that does also not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a logged in user the access control filter would kick in and redirect you to "home".  The only action you're allowed to perform on the controller is "login", so index is part of the denied actions.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I want that not logged in redirect to the login page. Not that they redirect to home. Where is it set that they should redirect to SiteController/Index?

Comment: The would be the "loginUrl" of the "user" application component. But by default that is already site/login.

Comment: I have added AdminModule.php because I have now set the loginUrl through $this->setComponents. But this does also not work.

Comment: Can you also add a $this->setComponent('user', NULL); in there and try again to be sure? The user component is initialized pretty much at the start. Updating the config does not create a new instance of it.

Comment: I have added it, and the same behavior occurred. Maybe I have to refactor everything to a Admin controller instead of a module because I am new to Yii. (Used Zend Framework before)

Comment: Perhaps make sure that everything works without the access control first, see if you can access all module actions correctly and so on. Try to confirm that the redirect is actually done by the filter. It's also possible that you mis-configured something related to the URL Routes in the config.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyModule extends CWebModule
{

    public function init()
    {

        ...

        Yii::app()->setComponents(array(
            'user'=>array(
                'class'=>'CWebUser',
                'stateKeyPrefix'=>'My',
                'loginUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->getId().'/default/login'),
            ),
        ), false);

       ...
```